# 404 when accessing the integrated WebLogic server console from JDeveloper 12.1.3

Tags: jdeveloper, weblogic12c, server-administration

I can start the integrated WebLogic application server from JDeveloper and can even deploy and test my servlets, but I cannot access the WebLogic console application (e.g. http://localhost:7101/console). My configuration has the port set as 7101 (my servlets are successfully executing on this port)

The strange thing is that until 2 days ago I was able to access the console and I'm not sure what I managed to snark up...

At this point I have uninstalled and reinstalled JDeveloper which did not help, I have no idea where to look for a log file that might be indicating an error condition but I have poked through a number of WebLogic log files, but these showed me nothing useful... (although I might well have been looking in the wrong location)...

Where should I look to find the appropriate log files?

What XML configuration files control how the console application is deployed (e.g. what its port and URL will be)...

Why didn't the uninstall / reinstall solve the problem?

Very frustrating... Help!

Comment: After 6 attempts (and 7 hours) to reinstall JDeveloper and the integrated WebLogic - I finally got a functional installation (including access to the administrative console)... the reasons for 6 attempts had to do with leftover scraps from the previous installation attempts interfering with the new installation - and my choice of configuration parameters (e.g. telling the integrated WebLogic server to use ports 7001 and 7002 (the same ones that the standalone version wants to use)...

Answer (score 1):

couple of suggestions - 
Firstly look for the number of java processes running and their PID's
Check what ports are in use. You say you are able to deploy and access your servlets which means that WLS is running, once you know which ports are in use you should get a clue for your wls admin console url.

Second option - 
Look for the file config.xml for your domain, this should have the listen address for the admin server. Check if you have configured a admin channel

Whats the url you are using to access your servlet ?

Comment: http://localhost:7101/cpd

the console always used to be on:

http://localhost:7101/console

Comment: on what operating system are you running on ? Assuming its windows you will need to run netstat -a -o and you will get the list of ports and pids from task manager under the details tab you will get the process name and pid.